# How to forcely uninstall mssql from ubuntu 16.04 system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I have tried following commands:

`sudo apt-get remove mssql-server`

`sudo apt-get -f`

but I get the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-tools : Depends: msodbcsql17 (>= 17.2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: msodbcsql17 (< 17.3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

kindly tell some working solution

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f install` (like the error suggests)

Comment: It is partially working but I want to uninstall completely

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix your missing dependencies, then execute `sudo apt-get remove mssql-server` to uninstall the server.

You can also delete the data directory using `sudo rm -rf /var/opt/mssql/`. (be extremely careful every time you use `sudo rm`, you could erase your entire hard drive if you specify the wrong path!)